# I wanna make a python script to open a certain app whenever I am not playing

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system

I wanna make a python script to open a certain app whenever I am not playing any video games any ideas how to do that???
your help is appreciated

Comment: Create a list of games you are playing. Create a whileloop and check the names of the games in processes. If there is no game in the processes, then start your thing.

Comment: how do I check if the names of the games are in the processes

Comment: I'd try listing like: https://thispointer.com/python-get-list-of-all-running-processes-and-sort-by-highest-memory-usage/. and create a simple for loop with if the name is in the list.

Comment: If you are looking for someone to create your code, try Fiverr. If you are looking for help with your code, provide some code first so we can help :)

Comment: I was just looking for the how to do it I think I can do it myself thnx for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this fairly simply by doing:

```
import os
os.chdir("C:/game/location")#enter where the game's .exe file is located
os.system("game.exe")#enter the exe filename
```

Comment: but how does the script know if I am playing or not

Comment: I've answered with another code block.

Answer (score 0):

To open the certain app, install psutil with `pip install psutil`.
Then:

```
import psutil
games_list = ["minecraft.exe"] #game exe file

for app in psutil.process_iter():
    if app.name() in games_list:
        print("Game {app.name()} open.") #output - "Game minecraft.exe open."
```